# How to reduce bundle size of main.js (Initial load) in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular 7 and it's a ERP system. It has approximately 150 component. The website's initial page loading time is quite long. I have used webpack-bundle-analyzer to analyse the bundle size of main.js. It's size is 700KB. I have used strategies like lazy-loading, preloading modules and files are gzipped.
I want to put the size of main.js(initial load) within 250KB-300KB. Is it possible? If yes, then what are approaches I can take?

I have given the analyzer image i get from webpack-bundle-analyzer.

[image]

Comment: Can you put analyzer graph image you have created with webpack-bundle-analyzer?

Comment: @GouravGarg I have edited my question and put the image.

Comment: Do you mean 700kB and 250-300kB gzipped?

Comment: Are you using AoT?

Comment: @Juthi this is not prod mode and aot mode.. can you please add image for that?

Answer (score 1):

Try moving to Angular 9, its new rendering engine called Ivy generates smaller bundles and it is backwards compatible so your code shouldn't have to change much.

Also, in the `main.js` the `compiler.js` is embedded which means you probably don't build in production mode (you're compiling "just in time", instead of "ahead of time").

Finally, you are loading big libraries like xlsx.js, jszip.js and cpexcel.js. Moving these libraries to lazy modules will help reduce the `main.js` size. If you need them on the very first pages of the app, then I guess you can't do much more.